# Priority between stylesheet and file .ui?

Tags: css, qt

I didn't find an answer on the net and i hope this question have not been made yet..in case i will delete my post..
now the question.
e.g. : i set an image on a `QPushButton` with `QtCreator` (or programmatically with QIcon etc..)
then i write a stylesheet where i set another image for the same button.
Is there some precedence between css and qtCreator files(.ui)?
which setting overcomes the other?

then i know two method to load a css on Qt application, so i think the method i use will determine the precedence. 
am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use setstylesheets in program, it will be used, guessing you are setting css in the constructor. If you don't set style sheet programmatically, css in .ui is used by default, if set css in both form(.ui) and programmatically, css set via program will be used. `The priority is for css set programmatically as it is executed later`!!

Answer (score 1):

If you set a stylesheet in QtCreator, this will be applied in the constructor of the widget/control when it executes the `setupUi()` function.

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
  setupUi(this); // here the stylesheet is applied
}
```

If you add code after this call, you can change whatever property of the user interface, or change the whole stylesheet by calling the `setStyleSheet()` function.

You can change the stylesheet for the whole application by calling `qApp->setStyLeSheet(...)` in the main.cpp file, also.